# pj_register_thread equivalent method in java/Android

Tags: android

We are integrating PJSUA2 into our Android Application. Everything is integrated and working fine. There is a random crash with the error log:

`../src/pj/os_core_unix.c:692: pj_thread_this: assertion "!"Calling pjlib from unknown/external thread. You must " "register external threads with pj_thread_register() " "before calling any pjlib functions."" failed`

What do this error mean?

We do not find `pj_thread_register()` method in java/Android PJSUA2. What is the equivalent method for this and how to use?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [PJSUA2 documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/reference.html), Use the following to register an external thread:

```
void Endpoint::libRegisterThread(const string &name)
```

To verify whether the thread is registered:

```
bool Endpoint::libIsThreadRegistered()
```